audio issues with tascam model 12 playback
I am having troubles recording on my tascam model 12. When I play back my tracks, the volume faders do nothing and only the aux 1 controls the volume of the playback track. I have tried making sure the mtr is set to return and I have verified the mode is in mtr. I am mixing in headphones, but when I mix down the track, transfer it, and then play it through my computer speakers, the levels of the tracks seem significantly different.

This is a question for TASCAM technical support, not here.
